# Tailwind - Laravel Mix - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve scss file

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-mix, postcss, tailwind-css

I am trying to install Tailwind into my Laravel 5.8 app and am using Laravel Mix. I've installed tailwind npm package and generated a tailwind config file. A file exists at the **resources/sass/app.scss** path but when I go to compile with `npm run watch` I get an error that a dependency was not found. How can I fix this and use Tailwind in my Laravel 5.8 project?

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                              12:16:17 PM

This dependency was not found:

* /Users/connorleech/Projects/employbl/resources/sass/app.scss in multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

To install it, you can run: npm install --save /Users/connorleech/Projects/employbl/resources/sass/app.scss
     Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
/js/app.js  2.37 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app

ERROR in multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/connorleech/Projects/employbl/resources/sass/app.scss' in '/Users/connorleech/Projects/employbl'
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

This is my **webpack.mix.js** file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').version();


mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.options({
  processCssUrls: false,
  postCss: [ tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js') ],
});
```

These are the dependencies in my **package.json**:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "vue": "^2.5.15"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "laravel-vue-pagination": "^2.3.0",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "npm": "^6.2.0",
        "pleasejs": "^0.4.2",
        "prod": "^1.0.1",
        "querystring": "^0.2.0",
        "run": "^1.4.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^1.2.0",
        "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.3",
        "vue-router": "^2.8.1",
        "vue-ua": "^1.5.0",
        "vuex": "^3.1.0"
    }
```

Comment: It seems there is a problem with addressing. Are your sure that your `app.js` resides in `assets` directory? Because from **Laravel 5.8** there is no `assets` folder in `resources` therefore your path should like `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').version();` i guess.

Comment: yes I do have an assets directory. I upgraded to 5.8 from an earlier Laravel version (5.4 i think)

Comment: Can you show contents of your resources directory? Your js is in assets and your sass isn't, so we need to see current file situation. A screenshot is fine

Comment: I gave up and am sticking with Bootstrap 4 :( Page is here: https://employbl.com/

Answer (score 0):

you missed the path `mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')`

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
 .options({
     processCssUrls: false,
     postCss: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js')],
 });
```